# how to sedn file with http requse?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am writing a test for multi process, I created a file in storage:

```
File::put($pathMainRNameFile)
```

now I want to call a spacial route like this:

```
     $result = $this->post('admin/file/upload', [
        's_file_id' => $sFiles->id,
        'main_file' => File::get($pathMainRNameFile),
        'sign_file' => File::get($pathSignRNameFile),
        'type' => \App\Enums\File\Type::REP,
    ]);
```

files has JSON extension.
but I get bad request error. How can I send file?